# when reading an html (pandas.read_html), how to select dataframe and set_ index in one line

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm reading an html which brings back a list of dataframes. I want to be able to choose the dataframe from the list and set my index (index_col) in the least amount of lines.

Here is what I have right now:

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_html('http://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx?or=-10&tv=100000&tc=1&o=-transactionvalue', header = 0)
df2 =df[4]   #here I'm assigning df2 to dataframe#4 from the list of dataframes I read
df2.set_index('Date', inplace =True)
```

Is it possible to do all this in one line? Do I need to create another dataframe (df2) to assign one dataframe from a list, or is it  possible I can assign the dataframe as soon as I read the list of dataframes (df).

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the least amount of lines? That is a weird requirement... Usually people are after the least amount of computation or least amount of time.

Comment: For learning purposes. I knew there was  way, but I couldn't figure out how to. So I was hoping someone could show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('http://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx?or=-10&tv=100000&tc=1&o=-transactionvalue', header = 0)[4].set_index('Date')
```